# What is valPtr in ctor of wxTextValidator good for?

Tags: c++, validation, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm using a simple numeric text validator **wxTextValidator** along with a **wxTextControl**. I wonder what the 2nd parameter is good for:

```
wxTextValidator(long style = wxFILTER_NONE, wxString* valPtr = NULL)
```

I simply passed the reference to a member variable:

```
myTextControl_->SetValidator( wxTextValidator(wxFILTER_NUMERIC, &myValue_) );
```

I'm using **wxWidgets 2.8.12**, from the documentation I figured that the **myValue_** variable would receive the validated content of the text control, but this does not happen in my application.

Am I doing something wrong or does the valPtr parameter **not** receive the content of the text control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The myvalue_ variable should receive the value entered if you call wxValidator::Validate or wxValidator::TransferFromWindow.  This happens automatically if you close the dialog with the default OnOK() handler.  Otherwise you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Aaaah, yes, RTFM ;-) Thank you, TransferFromWindow did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ravenspoint has already answered the initial question but I'd just like to add that `wxValidator` can be used either for validating or for data transfer -- or for both at once. In fact, some validators, such as [wxGenericValidator](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_generic_validator.html) are only used for data transfer (it doesn't make much sense to validate a check box or a radio button!). So the name of this class is somewhat misleading as it describes at most half, and probably less than that, of its uses.